# Does dereferencing a pointer create a copy in this example?

Tags: c++, qt, dereference, qpixmap

I'm attempting to optimize some code because I must draw the same QPixmap onto a larger one many many times. Since passing a QPixmap by value in my own methods would create copies with each call, I thought I could shave some time off by working with pointers to QPixmaps. However, it seems my work has been in vein. I think it's because calling QPainter::drawPixmap(..., const QPixmap&, ...) creates a copy of it.

```
QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap(10,10);
painter.drawPixmap(0,0, *pixmap);
```

Is a copy being created in this example?

If so, how might I go about optimizing the drawing many images onto another?

I have already read this Q/A here: [Does dereferencing a pointer make a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436805/does-dereferencing-a-pointer-make-a-copy-of-it) but a definite answer for my specific case eludes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [QPixmap class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#details):

> QPixmap objects can be passed around by value since the QPixmap class
>   uses implicit data sharing. For more information, see the Implicit
>   Data Sharing documentation.

QPixmap implementation:

```
QPixmap::QPixmap(const QPixmap &pixmap)
    : QPaintDevice()
{
    if (!qt_pixmap_thread_test()) {
        init(0, 0, QPixmapData::PixmapType);
        return;
    }
    if (pixmap.paintingActive()) {                // make a deep copy
        operator=(pixmap.copy());
    } else {
        data = pixmap.data;
    }
}
```

Only when the pixmap is painting active you'll need a deep copy otherwise the new pixmap would only need to copy the orignal data pointer.

For difference of const reference and pointer:

```
QPixmap largeMap(1000, 1000);
QPainter p(&largeMap);

int count = 100000;
qint64 time1, time2;
QPixmap *pSmallMap = new QPixmap("e:/test.png");
QPixmap smallMap = QPixmap("e:/test.png");

time1 =  QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, *pSmallMap);
}
time2 =  QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();;
qDebug("def time = %d\n", time2 - time1);

time1 =  QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, smallMap);
}
time2 =  QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();;
qDebug("normal time = %d\n", time2 - time1);
```

compile under visual studio 2010 **Debug** configuration would produce following assembly :

```
    28:         p.drawPixmap(0, 0, *pSmallMap);
003B1647 8B 55 C4             mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]  //the pixmap pointer
003B164A 52                   push        edx  
003B164B 6A 00                push        0  //x
003B164D 6A 00                push        0  //y
003B164F 8D 4D F0             lea         ecx,[ebp-10h]  //the qpainter pointer
003B1652 FF 15 9C D7 3B 00    call        dword ptr [__imp_QPainter::drawPixmap (3BD79Ch)]

    35:         p.drawPixmap(0, 0, smallMap);
003B16A8 8D 4D E0             lea         ecx,[ebp-20h]  //the pixmap pointer
003B16AB 51                   push        ecx            
003B16AC 6A 00                push        0              //x
003B16AE 6A 00                push        0              //y
003B16B0 8D 4D F0             lea         ecx,[ebp-10h]  //the qpainter pointer
003B16B3 FF 15 9C D7 3B 00    call        dword ptr [__imp_QPainter::drawPixmap (3BD79Ch)]
```

There should be no differece between this two, because the compiler will produce the same assembly code: pass the pointer to the drawPixmap function.

And QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() nearly show the same result on my box.

Comment: Probably not *strictly* true. In his case, he's actually passing by reference, so it doesn't matter. If he passed by value, it would certainly have *some*, although potentially negligible, overheard greater than the reference passing mechanism.

Comment: Right.. The difference is only about 1 second every 100k draws.

Comment: @Sosukodo: since your code using reference, there should be no performance difference bettween reference and point. How do you get the performance difference?

Comment: How did I calculate it? Basically delta of  QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() before and after the 100k calls to drawPixmap.

Comment: Thanks. You definitely earned that one!

Answer (score 4):

No. The function `drawPixmap` takes a `const` reference to the `pixmap`, so there is no copy being made. Here's the prototype for the QPainter member function:

```
  void  drawPixmap ( int x, int y, const QPixmap & pixmap )
```