# c++ std::holds_alternative with custom type (class)?

Tags: c++, enums, union, variant

I am learning c++23 after rust. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017982/c-equivalent-of-rust-enums) question explains variant matching in c++ with usage of `std::visit`. On the other hand, *A Tour of C++* gives examples of `std::holds_alternative`. This example works:

```cpp
struct GoodEntry {
    std::variant<float*,int> v;
};

void f(GoodEntry* pe) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(pe->v)){
        std::cout << std::get<int>(pe ->v) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```cpp
struct Quit {};
struct Move { int32_t x; int32_t y; };
struct Write { std::string s; };
struct ChangeColor { int32_t r; int32_t g; int32_t b; };
using Message = std::variant<Quit, Move, Write, ChangeColor>;

void f2(Message* pm) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<Move>(pm)){
        std::cout << std::get<Move>(pm ->x) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Why does compilation fail with
`error: no matching function for call to 'holds_alternative<Move>(Message*&)'` ?

Comment: Silly typos: https://godbolt.org/z/497q9xr5e

Comment: @MarekR, not a typo. Just lack of knowledge. I am learning c++, and didn't realise pe->v copies the value.

Comment: **pe->v copies the value.** No, it does not.

Comment: @273K, it seems it does. `auto q = Move{1,2};`, then `Move* yy = &q;`, then `int* z = yy->y;`. Last step won't compile.  Although, I can achieve `int* z` by using references. Also this seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436805/does-dereferencing-a-pointer-make-a-copy-of-it,

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about in your last comment. As for the link, your case is #2 in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first snippet there is a `struct GoodEntry` that has a `std::variant` member field. In the second one you have a typedef `Message` that IS a `std::variant`, so you would need to first dereference your `pm`:

```
void f2(Message* pm) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<Move>(*pm)){
        std::cout << std::get<Move>(*pm).x << std::endl;
    }
}
```